# nodejs iconv invalid ELF header error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio, iconv

I'm checking on my local(mac terminal, with node web.js)

and I checked it is running on local server.

However, when I deploy it to the server, it keeps making error as

Error: /home/hosting_users/***/apps/***/node_modules/iconv/build/Release/iconv.node: invalid ELF header

In details,[ERROR LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1dEv.png)

How can I make it running on the server?

have no idea please help.

This code is what I use Iconv in my code.

```js
const Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;

var iconv = new Iconv('euc-kr', 'utf-8//translit//ignore');

var option = {
    url: url,
    transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(iconv.convert(body).toString());
    },
    encoding: null
};
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you copy your `node_modules` directory to a different *platform* (e.g. Mac to Linux, Linux to Windows, etc.), you need to recompile any binary addons. You should be able to accomplish this by doing `npm rebuild`.

In this specific situation, you *could* use `iconv-lite` instead which does not require compilation and seems to be faster than `iconv`.